# Clean event viewer files

Tags: windows-10, event-viewer

Does anyone know how can I clean the event viewer old logs so I can free space in the disk?

My operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: Do you have the authority and authorization to clean the event logs.  If you do, you can delete the logs, within the event viewer itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right-click each of the logs in Event Viewer and choose "Clear Log". They are typically only 20MB (or less) and overwrite events as needed, but you can right-click and choose "Properties" to adjust this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I clean the event viewer old logs?

The quickest way is to use an elevated command prompt.

> **Clear All Event Logs in Windows 10 using Command Prompt**
>
> You can quickly clear all event logs using a special command. Do it as
>   follows.
>
> 1. [Open an elevated command prompt](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-in-windows-10/).
> 2. Type or paste the following command:
>
>    ```
>    for /F "tokens=*" %1 in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO wevtutil.exe cl "%1"
>    ```
>
> This will produce the following output:
>
> [image]
>
> All Windows logs will be cleared.

Source [How to Clear All Event Logs in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-clear-all-event-logs-in-windows-10/)